# How to use bigrock's mx records into infinityfree hosting?

Tags: email, dns, hosting, mx-record

I am having an email from big rock, and hosting from infinityfree and domain from godaddy. How to connect email?

Answer (score 0):

You can point your domain to Infinity name server first. Once it is done, you can login to your infinityname server control panel and then change your MX settings. Please make sure you are using correct MX settings from Bigrock.